# zend framework 2 URL parse

Tags: parsing, url, zend-framework2, uri

how can i parse URL in zend framework 2?

my link is

my module.config.php looks like this

```
<?php return array(
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(

        'read' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/read',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Read\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'wildcard' => array(
                    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Wildcard',
                    'options' => array(
                        'key_value_delimiter' => '/',
                        'param_delimiter' => '/',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),

'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Read\Controller\Index' => 'Read\Controller\ReadController'
    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(

    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),);
```

my full URL is

> lhost/test.net/read/id/qwerty

and i need to get "qwerty" part is there any way to get it with zf2?
i can get full url with `$this->serverUrl(true);` but was unable to retrive jsut that last part ( dont wanna use PHP to parse it if possible

Comment: The Wildcard route type is [deprecated](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-wildcard-deprecated) a while ago because of some potential security issues. You should use the Segment route type instead of Wildcard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got answer for this in case anyone will need this

module config:

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'read' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/read/id', /* Need close slash '/' */
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Read\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'news' => '[A-Z]+', /* Mask for first paremeter need different from second parameter */
                    )
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/[:news]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'news' => '.*', /* Mask for first parameter need different from second parameter */
                            ),
                            'key_value_delimiter' => '/',
                            'param_delimiter' => '/',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

contoller :

```
$news = $this->params()->fromRoute('news');

return new ViewModel(array('news' => $news));
```

and phtml file

just call it `$news`

Answer (score 0):

routes

```
...
    'read' => array(
        'type'    => 'Segment',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/read[/:first][/:second][/]', /* Need close slash '/' */
            'defaults' => array(
                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Read\Controller',
                'controller'    => 'Index',
                'action'        => 'index',
                'first'         => 'default',
                'second'        => 'default'
            ),
            'constraints' => array(
                'first' => '[0-9]+', /* Mask for first paremeter need different from second parameter */
                'second' => '[a-z]+' /* Mask for second parameter need different from first parameter */
            )
        )
...
```

In controller

```
...Action()
...
    $this->params('first');
    $this->params('second');
...
```

Comment: "A 404 error occurred
Page not found.
The requested URL could not be matched by routing.

No Exception available"